# ASP.NET Core MVC in Visual Studio for Mac can't run with the new update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

After the last Visual Studio macOS update (April 23, 2023), my ASP.NET Core MVC project doesn't run, neither returns any error, just stops before it starts in the browser, doesn't matter if its Chrome, Safari or another browser.

I tried to rebuild, reopen Visual Studio, checked the database connection, restarted my Mac, but nothing works.

If someone could help me would be great, before the update I have been working with no problem, it probably changed the Visual Studio libs but I don't know how to solve it.

Example of my project:

```cs
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(ms);

byte[] stream = ms.ToArray();

Download obj = new Download();
obj.Nome = "RelatorioTituloPagar";
obj.IsTerminou = 1;

_context.Download.Update(obj);
_context.SaveChanges();

return File(stream, "application/pdf", "titulos-pagos-" + DateTime.Now.ToString(string.Format("dd/MM/yyyy")) + ".pdf");
```

Comment: What do you mean "just stops before it starts in the browser"? If you view the network requests in your browser's developer tools, what does it reveal about the request?